# How can I execute code when a HTML element (total number of orders remaining) reaches "0"?

Tags: javascript

I have a 1 second interval set, which essentially checks whether the total orders has reached zero each time the interval passes. The trouble with this is that the code within the if statement continues to run each second once the condition is met.

```
if (theHours >= 16 && theHours < 17) {
  function ordersComplete() {
    let totalRemaining = document.getElementById("total-remaining");
    if (totalRemaining.textContent == 0) {
      console.log("nice swan");
    }
  };
  setInterval(ordersComplete, 1000);
}
```

Comment: co clear the interval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decide dynamically whether another invocation of the function is necessary, I suggest to replace the use of `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. This can be used for a recursive delayed invocation:

```js
function ordersComplete() {
  let totalRemaining = document.getElementById("total-remaining");
  if (totalRemaining.textContent == 0) {
    console.log("nice swan");
  } else {
    setTimeout(ordersComplete, 1000);
  };
}
if (theHours >= 16 && theHours < 17) {
  ordersComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearInterval()` when you want to stop the timer.

```
if (theHours >= 16 && theHours < 17) {
  let interval = setInterval(ordersComplete, 1000);
  function ordersComplete() {
    let totalRemaining = document.getElementById("total-remaining");
    if (totalRemaining.textContent == 0) {
      console.log("nice swan");
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your function inside of your `if` statement, which is causing your problem.

You'll instead want to declare your function separately, and then call it when you're supposed to.

```
function ordersComplete(){
     let totalRemaining = document.getElementById("total-remaining");
     if (totalRemaining.textContent == 0) {
        console.log("nice swan");
     }
};
if(theHours >= 16 && theHours < 17){
    setInterval(ordersComplete, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this would make a difference. It still doesn't stop repeating when the condition is no longer met.

Comment: You're absolutely right - definitely though the `setInterval` was a `setTimeout` and just ran with the first potential problem I saw.